# A Query that works in rails console doesn't work as a method

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to have a weighted average of values like this:

```
c = Company.select('sum(pbr * market_cap) / sum(market_cap) as foo')
[
    [0] #<Company:0x007f8d97819620> {
        :id => nil
    }
]
c.first.foo
1.912815559952786983747597339216657074310395339
```

It works fine. But when I create a method and call it, then it ends up error like this:

```
  Company Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  sum(pbr * market_cap) / sum(market_cap) as foo FROM "companies"  ORDER BY "companies"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "companies.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 1: ...sum(market_cap) as foo FROM "companies"  ORDER BY "companies...
                                                             ^
: SELECT  sum(pbr * market_cap) / sum(market_cap) as foo FROM "companies"  ORDER BY "companies"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "companies.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 1: ...sum(market_cap) as foo FROM "companies"  ORDER BY "companies...
                                                             ^
: SELECT  sum(pbr * market_cap) / sum(market_cap) as foo FROM "companies"  ORDER BY "companies"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
from /Users/ironsand/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-mini-profiler-0.9.6/lib/patches/db/pg.rb:90:in `exec'
```

The error occurs also when I use method chain.

```
Company.select('sum(pbr * market_cap) / sum(market_cap) as foo').first.foo
```

Why is this error happens? and how can fix it?

Comment: In the console, what is the value of `c.class`? What if you try `Company.select('sum(pbr * market_cap) / sum(market_cap) as foo').to_a.first.foo`?

Comment: Could you post exactly what you have in the method call? Something somewhere is adding an ordering: `ORDER BY "companies"."id" ASC` and that is what is breaking.

Comment: Also, could you post each method as `to_sql`?

Comment: @Owen Thanks, with `to_a` I can get the value. `c.class` was `Company::ActiveRecord_Relation < ActiveRecord::Relation`. Now I understand why `first causes the error.

Comment: @evanbikes Thanks for the advice. the method `ActiveRecord::Relation#first` insert the `ORDER` claused to get first element.